# How to remove all nonnumber string characters from list?

Tags: python

I have a list I want to remove all non numeric string values from.

```
list = ['$\\mathdefault{10}$', '$\\mathdefault{30}$', '$\\mathdefault{50}$']
```

would become:

```
newlist = [10,30,50]
```

I have tried:

```
>> [x for x in mylist if not isinstance(x, str)]
>> [x for x in mylist if isinstance(x, int)]
>> [x for x in mylist if isinstance(x, float)]
```

all return empty: `[]` presumably because even the numbers are strings.

How to achieve: `[10,30,50]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mylist = ['$\\mathdefault{10}$', '$\\mathdefault{30}$', '$\\mathdefault{50}$']

result = [int(''.join(i for i in x if i.isdigit())) for x in mylist]
```

Output:

```
[10, 30, 50]
```

Explanation:

```
result = [             # 6. list comprehension to build the resulting ints
  int(                 # 5. convert to int
    ''.join(           # 4. concatenate the matched digit strings
      i for i in x     # 2. loop through each character in x
      if i.isdigit()   # 3. check if character (i) is a digit (0-9)
    )
  )
  for x in mylist      # 1. loop through each string in mylist
]
```

Comment: Thanks this one was the easiest for me to understand.

Answer (score 2):

```py
newlist = [int(''.join(char for char in string if char.isdigit())) for string in mylist]
```

You're actually doing a few things, which is why you end up with this gnarly 1-liner. Each item in your list needs to have all the non-numeric characters stripped out. That's the `char.isdigit()` part. Then the remaining numeric string characters need to be joined together.  That's the `''.join(...)` part. Then they need to be cast to int, the `int(...)` part. And all that is wrapped in an list comprehension so you end up with a list of ints.

```py
>> [x for x in mylist if not isinstance(x, str)]
>> [x for x in mylist if isinstance(x, int)]
>> [x for x in mylist if isinstance(x, float)]
```

The reason none of these worked is because their acting on the whole strings in the list, rather than the characters in each string.  Also, even though they are numeric characters, they're still strings. So `isinstance()` will not separate them from the letters and other characters.

Comment: Thanks this one was easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

using regex

```
list = ['$\\mathdefault{10}$', '$\\mathdefault{30}$', '$\\mathdefault{50}$']

import re
array = [int(re.findall(r'[0-9]+', i)[0]) for i in list]

print(array)
[10, 30, 50]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = ['$\\mathdefault{10}$', '$\\mathdefault{30}$', '$\\mathdefault{50}$']
import string
def parse_digits(text):
    return int(''.join([char for char in text if char in string.digits]))
ml = [parse_digits(item) for item in my_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
listInput = ['$\\mathdefault{10}$', '$\\mathdefault{30}$', '$\\mathdefault{50}$']
newlist = []

for i in listInput:

    numbers = re.findall('[0-9]+', i)
    if(len(numbers) > 0):
        newlist.append(int(numbers[0]))

print(newlist)
```

https://pythonexamples.org/python-regex-extract-find-all-the-numbers-in-string/

Answer (score 1):

This is the shortest way of getting your problem solved:

```py
myList = ['$\\mathdefault{10}$', '$\\mathdefault{30}$', '$\\mathdefault{50}$']
onlyTheNumbers = list(map(lambda y: int("".join([z for z in y if z.isnumeric()])), myList))
print(onlyTheNumbers)
# output: [10, 30, 50]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have all the strings with the same pattern `$\\mathdefault{number}$` you can use slicing:

```
[int(i[14:-2]) for i in lst]
# [10, 30, 50]
```

alternatively, you can use a regex:

```
import re

p = re.compile(r'\d+')
[int(p.search(i).group(0)) for i in lst]
# [10, 30, 50]
```

Comment: nice! would have worked in my case. But i decided to go with a more general method. thanks!